# Why does $\sum_{j\ne i} E[y_iy_j] =(n-1)\mu^2$

Tags: statistics

**Background:** I'm trying to understand why the Sample Covariance matrix is divided by $N-1$ in $\frac{1}{N-1}BB^T$ which really is just another way of asking why the variance of a sample is averaged by N-1 and not N. I remember vaguely that it had something to do with degrees of freedom but it's unimportant for the question:

In the expected value of a sample variance I don't understand how the following line is simplified:
$$E[\sigma^2_y]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[\frac{n-2}{n}E[y_i^2]-\color{red}{\frac{2}{n}\sum_{j\ne i}^{n}E[y_iy_j]+\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k\ne j}^{n}E[y_jy_k]}+\sum_{j=1}^nE[y_j]^2\right]$$

The red is simplified to $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[\frac{n-2}{n}(\sigma^2+\mu^2)-\color{red}{\frac{2}{n}(n-1)\mu^2+\frac{1}{n^2}n(n-1)\mu^2}+\frac{1}{n}((\sigma^2+\mu^2)\right ]$$

How is $E[y_iy_j]=\mu^2$? It seems to me that would never be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't; $\sum_{j\ne i}E[Y_iY_j]=n(n-1)\mu^2$. There are $n^2-n$ terms
in the sum. Each equals $\mu^2$, since, as $Y_i$ and $Y_j$ are independent
when $i\ne j$, $E[Y_iY_j]=E[Y_i]E[Y_j]=\mu\mu=\mu^2$.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Say we take the numbers 1,2,3. $\mu^2=4$ but $E[X_iY_i]=(2+3+2+6+3+6)/6=3\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: @user135711 I get that $4=(1+2+3+2+4+6+3+6+9)/9$.

Comment: But I thought $i\ne j$ meant these values aren't included 1*1, 2*2 and 3*3?

Comment: @user135711 So that's the source of your confusion. If say you are rolling dice, then $E(Y_iY_j)$ is the product of the $i$-th and $j$-th dice rolls. Those could be the same number!